# Selenium opens firefox and stops all processes

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

i am automating a process on firefox using selenium with c# .NET4.0:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://www.microsoft.com/");

        selenium.Start();
        selenium.SetSpeed("900");

        selenium.WindowMaximize();
        selenium.WindowFocus();

        Login();
     }

public static void LogIn()
        {
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();

        selenium.SetSpeed("900");
        selenium.Open("/Login.aspx");

        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_cphBody_objLogin_UserName", "user");

        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_cphBody_objLogin_Password", "P@assword");

        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_cphBody_objLogin_LoginImageButton");

        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");    

            try
            {
                selenium.IsTextPresent("Orders - Drug Testing");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could't find text: Orders - Drug Testing.");

            }


    }
```

firefox opens, and then NOTHING happens at all. it does not navigate to the requested page.

here's what it looks like. what am i doing wrong? everything works fine with `IE`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate to the requested page, need to use the following piece of code.

Selenium doesn't navigate to the page or base url automatically until & unless you call

```
selenium.open(" < your url goes here > ");
```

Ex : `selenium.open("https://mail.google.com");`

Comment: thank you very much for your help. that is a great point, and i should have included the rest of my code to show you that i did this already. ive updated my question

Comment: Did you try with the standard version of firefox 5.x or 3.6.x

Comment: i will award the bounty in 22 hours, as soon as i can!